How to mark custom object in 2nd generation package as protected?
On https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg1_dev.meta/pkg1_dev/packaging_protected_components.htm it states that certain components can be mark protected so the subscriber organization can not see them. I can not see anyway to create a custom object and mark it as protected and would like to know what the correct way to do that is? Also is there a way to check if an existing custom object is protected?

This is possible as per the Second-Generation Managed Packaging Developer Guide, specifically Hide Custom Objects and Custom Permissions in Your Subscribers’ Orgs.
To do this, when creating the Object you need to set the Visibility attribute in the Custom Object definition to 'Protected'
<visibility>Protected</visibility>
Likewise, you can use this attribute to determine whether an Object is protected or not.
